# Installing ruby / gems / jekyll on mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, ruby, rubygems

I tried to install newer version of ruby, because I needed it for install the Jekyll. Now when I try to use any gem command (i.e. gem install jekyll) I get a my little pony image in the Terminal and a message saying that internet is a dangerous place and a command for uninstall but it's not working anyway.

This pony is pasted each second till infinity.

http://prntscr.com/bbnbf1

Can anyone help pls?

Comment: Where did you get this newer version of Ruby from?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran across [this gem](https://github.com/hdm/ruby-gem-install), which was made as a joke but has now been pulled from RubyGems. Beats me how you got it (typoed?), but in any case, follow the instructions for the command they give (`gem uninstall install -x`) and you should be fine.